# HTTP Server Multiplexer/Tunneler(Proxy)

Tags: http, http-proxy, multiplexing

I'm looking for a HTTP Server Multiplexer because I've only one public IP and I need use two different Web Servers (Tomcat and IIS) on the same port (the 80). So I thought that is possible use a multiplexer to tunnel all traffic for iis.mydomain.com to the internal port of IIS (for example the 81) and tunnel all the traffic for apache.mydomain.com to the internal port of Tomcat (for example 82).

I think the multpliplexer must choose the correct tunnel reading the HTTP-Host header. And this way makes all transparent to the internet browser, because I use tunnels, not redirects.

Am I wrong?
Is there an existing software for Windows?

Comment: use rewrite module, for iis7 or apache

Comment: mod_rewrite of Apache can tunnel a connection to IIS?

Comment: yes, you can redirect all traffic based on its packets header to any ip:port on a local or remote host.if you interesting this, i can provide you a sample

Comment: Yes I am! Please provide a sample and write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to install mod_proxy & mod-rewrite.on windows or many linux ditributions these modules are installed by default, so you may found them on `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\modules` in windows and `/usr/lib/apache2/modules` in linux.

so you need to load them via apache config:

unix-like os:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

windows:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

then configure two virtual hosts on your apache:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName iis.mydomain.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:81/$1 [P]    
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName apache.mydomain.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:82/$1 [P]    
</VirtualHost>
```

[image]

for more information please see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html) and [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

**EDIT 1:**

An [article](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html) about using apache on windows

Comment: thanks! Finally I used apache with mod_proxy and the ProxyPass option